# Routing not working when i click second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

hi all I am using angularjs and working with routing functionality (Route provider) it's working for first time only when I click the second menu it's not redirect and I am not getting any error also in console help how to solve here i attached my code

## code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  ng-app="app" >
    <head>
    <script src="assets/js/AngularJS1.3.12.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="controller/module.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="no-skin" >
      <a href="#/managerole">role</a> 
        or 
     <a href="#/manageuser">user</a>
     <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## module.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", [  "ngRoute"]);
// configure our routes
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider',function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,  $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        // route for the about page
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'UnderConstruction.html'

        })
        .when('/managerole', {
            templateUrl: 'role.html',
            controller: 'RoleViewCtrlq'
        })
        .when('/manageuser', {
            templateUrl: 'user.html',
            controller: 'UserController' 
        });


}]);

    app.controller('RoleViewCtrlq', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an Role  page.';
    });

    app.controller('UserController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message ='Look! I am an user  page.';
    });
```

Comment: Try this:  <a href="#manageuser">user</a>

Comment: @Ved same first click working second click not working

Comment: what do you mean by first click working and second not. remove `/` and check. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you forget to add ng-view tag  in your Html page

here is below sample to help you

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing_controller

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<body class="no-skin" >
      <a href="#!managerole">role</a> 
        or 
     <a href="#!manageuser">user</a>
     <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
```